# How to properly set the redirectUri when using Expo AuthSession with Azure and Azure Active Directory?

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, expo

there is a problem with the redirect when getting the AccessToken.

This is the error:

Invariant violation: `AccessTokenRequest` requires a valid `redirectUri` (must also match the one used in the authentication request). Example: myapp://redirect

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [discovery, setDiscovery] = useState([]);
    const [authRequest, setAuthRequest] = useState([]);
    const [authorizeResult, setAuthorizeResult] = useState(null);

    const scopes = ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"];
    const domain = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenetID}/v2.0`;
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: "exp",
        useProxy: false,
        host: "183.132.2.19000",
      });

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSession = async () => {
            try {
                const d = await AuthSession.fetchDiscoveryAsync(domain);
               // console.log("Obj authSession",d)
                const authRequestOptions = {
                    prompt: AuthSession.Prompt.Login,
                    responseType: AuthSession.ResponseType.Code,
                    scopes: scopes,
                    usePKCE: true,
                    clientId: clientID,
                    redirectUri: redirectUrl,
                };
                const authRequest = new AuthSession.AuthRequest(authRequestOptions);
                //console.log("Auth request options:", authRequestOptions.scopes);
                setAuthRequest(authRequest);
                setDiscovery(d);
                //console.info("Discovery object:", d);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };
        getSession();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCodeExchange = async () => {
            try {
                console.log('entro')
                const tokenResult = await AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync({
                    grant_type: "authorization_code",
                    code: authorizeResult.params.code,
                    client_id: clientID,
                    client_secret: clientSecret,
                    redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
                    extraParams: {
                        code_verifier: authRequest.codeVerifier || "",
                    },
                }, 
                discovery,
                console.log('segunda entrada')
                );
                console.log('redirect_uri:', redirectUrl);
               // console.log("Token scopes:", tokenResult);
                console.log('tecera entrada')

                const { access_token, refresh_token, expires_in } = tokenResult;
                console.log("Response accessToken from Graph v2", access_token);
                setToken(access_token)
                console.info(access_token)
                const response = await fetch(
                    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                        },
                    }
                );
                console.log("Response from Graph API:", response);
                //givenName surname userPrincipalName id
                const responseJson = await response.json();
                // console.log("Access token scopes:", responseJson.scope);
                console.info(responseJson)
                const { givenName } = responseJson;

                setUsername(responseJson.givenName);
                // setEmail(responseJson.mail);
                // setId(responseJson.id);
                console.log(givenName)
                return navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("error capa 1 "+error);
            }
        };

        if (authorizeResult && authorizeResult.type === "success" && authRequest) {
            getCodeExchange();
        }
    }, [authorizeResult, authRequest, discovery, clientID, redirectUrl, navigation]);
```